# Execute saved query and retrieve results in access 2007

Tags: ms-access

Here is the problem I have. I need to execute a saved query that accepts parameters from an entry in a form. After the query is executed, I need to retrieve the selected value. How do I go about doing that?

I understand I can execute the query using CurrentDB.Openrecordset("myquery"). I want to use ADO for this.

I was able to insert rows to the table using ADO.

Appreciate your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Access VBA with ADO by treating the query as a Stored Procedure, like so:

```vbs
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "yourQueryName"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("yourParameterName", adInteger, adParamInput, , 5)
Set rst = cmd.Execute
Do Until rst.EOF
    Debug.Print rst(0).Value
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks. So if there is a form variable that I need to use as a parameter, how would I pass that? I know typically we pass it this way                [Forms]![TaskEntry]![cbovar];

Comment: The form accepts a text variable that I need to pass on to the query. So this variable acts as a parameter in the WHERE clause